# Get an Observable<Response> with angular 9 / 10

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use [ngx-filesaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver) to download a file in an angular app.
I'm trying to use the example under [Custom HTTP type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver#custom-http-type) on that page, but whatever I do I can't get `httpClient` to return an `Observable<Response>`

Right now I have this :

```js
    const key = this.selected.Key.slice(7).replace(/Json/, '');
    let res = this.myService.getFile(key, 'blob');
    return (res);

[...]

  public getFile(key : string, responseType)
  {
    var headers = this.mkHeaders();
    return (this.httpClient.get(myLink + key, {headers, responseType, observe: responseType == 'blob' ? 'response' : null}).pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError)));
  }
```

This returns an `Observable<HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>>`.
Any tips on how I could do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this._httpClient.get(myLink + key, {
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'blob'
}
```

Did you have a look at [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-filesaver)?

Comment: Hi, unless I'm mistaken that's exactly what I have in my post, and it returns an `Observable<HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>>`. I found another solution though, posting it in an answer

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, works great :

```
      this.myService.getFile(key, "text").pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((data: any) =>
      {
        var content = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
        this._FileSaverService.save(content, key);
      });
```

Just getting the file as text then making the Blob myself works.